# Google Chrome "Privacy error" for a few select sites

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

Today I started seeing the "Privacy error" in Chrome for a few select pages, like apple.stackexchange.com and macworld.com. Not all sites, just a few. The error message looks like this:
[image: Your Connection Is Not Private]

My Chrome version is up-to-date (ie. version 94) and the OS is 10.11.6.

I'm resorting to Firefox to write this. I don't remember changing anything in particular.

What could be the cause for this error message to crop up?

Comment: Possibly this - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370443/invalid-certificate-on-all-se-sites